# Relationship between input size and number of filters on each Conv2D layer in a U-NET

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have this U-NET implementation:

```
import numpy as np 
import os
import skimage.io as io
import skimage.transform as trans
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as keras

def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (240, 240, 1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)

    model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

When I change its `input_size` parameter to `(200, 200, 1)` it fails with this error:

```
A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 25, 25, 512), (None, 24, 24, 512)]
```

At this line:

```
merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
```

I think the problem is related to the size of the filters in [Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) layers.

Is there any relationship between `input_size` and filters size in all `Conv2D` layers?

If there is any relationship, I could fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the interaction between `MaxPooling2D` and `UpSampling2D` layers, actually. With an `input_size` of `(200, 200, 1)`, the side length of the output of your layers goes from `200` -> `100` -> `50` -> `25` -> `12`, because `MaxPooling2D` rounds the size down. When you use `UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))`, it just doubles the dimension and sends `12` -> `24`, which isn't compatible with `25`.

What you need to do is use an upsampling layer that upsamples to a specific shape, not by a specific factor. The way I've done this is to wrap `tf.image.resize` in a `Lambda` layer.

```
my_upsampling_layer = Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image,...
    tf.convert_to_tensor(enc_layer.shape[1:3])),output_shape=list(enc_layer.shape[1:]))
```

`enc_layer` would be the corresponding layer on the downslope of the U, since you need to match its size when you're going up the U.

Comment: So, I think that I have to use is this: `my_upsampling_layer = Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image,tf.convert_to_tensor(drop4.shape[1:3])),output_shape=list(drop4.shape[1:]))`. And then use it here: `up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(my_upsampling_layer(drop5))`. Isn't it? Because I have tried and it works, but I'm not sure what I did. Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel Yeah, that's correct. Now, instead of resizing `drop5` to `(24,24,1)`, you're resizing it to `(25,25,1)`, which lets it be concatenated with `drop4`. If you want your U-net to be able to handle an image of any size, you should change all of your `UpSampling2D` layers to be these custom upsampling layers. As it is right now, your U-net will only work if the image size is evenly divisible by 8. If you change all the upsampling layers, it should work no matter what size the input is.

Comment: Another question. How can I know the output shape for each layer. with `model.summary()`? This the line for the first up_sampling: `up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D)    (None, 50, 50, 512)  0           conv2d_12[0][0] `. The column for the output shape is `(None, 50, 50, 512)` , and the previous layer output shape is `(None, 25, 25, 512)` . Where does `(None, 24, 24, 512)` shape come from? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel It comes from `pool4`, which reduces the size from `(25,25)` to `(12,12)`, and then from up6, which increases the size from `(12,12)` to `(24,24)` (if you only use `UpSampling2D`).

Comment: I think your solution doesn't work on Tensorflow 2.1.0, Keras 2.3.7 and Python 3.7.7. I get the error: `Unexpected keyword argument 'output_shape' in constructor call`. By the way, I import `Lambda` from sympy.